# Net::SMTPServerBusy Relay access denied Mailjet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, environment-variables, mailjet

I am receiving this error when trying to send Mailjet email from my production server:

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy (454 4.7.1 <email@example.com>: Relay access denied
)
```

Here is my `config/initializers/mail.rb` file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'in.mailjet.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:port           => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => ENV['MAILJET_USERNAME'],
:password       => ENV['MAILJET_PASSWORD'],
:domain         => 'example.com'
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same thing here for mailjet.  Works fine in production on my local machine but when I go to AWS it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using Mailjet !

I would like to check one thing with you before moving on.

Are talking of using :

1. the **API key** as **MAILJET_USERNAME** ?
2. the **API secret** as **MAILJET_PASSWORD** ?

Some of our users are mixing them with login and password.
The key and secret may be found in your account, under the REST API section.